# Get in Someone like that’s car. Or Get in someone's like that car

Tags: possessives, noun-phrases

Which is correct "Get in someone like that’s car." Or, "Get in someone's like that car."?.

Comment: Your phrases do not make sense. Are you asking the difference between "**that car**" and "**that's car**"?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Because both of your examples aren't exactly Standard English, and one is very strange indeed, it's hard to know exactly what your asking for. Perhaps you could explain the situation in which you would be saying it? That would enable us to help you more.

Comment: Hi it's about possession I want to use the 's instead of saying "Why would get in the car of someone like that.". I don't know if I should add it  to that or someone I was reading a book and read a similar phrase with the 's on that  but i think it should be on someone..

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide two grammatical sentences. (Or at least one, with the second being a variation that you're asking about.) As it stands, neither of these sentences are grammatical.

Comment: What's wrong with those sentences? If you got into the car of someone who is bad  I could ask you that.

Comment: Perhaps you can hyphenate the phrase: “someone-like-that’s” to make it clearer how it should be parsed.

Answer (score 2):

The clitic `'s` is standard only for actual nouns. Using it for an entire noun phrase is on shaky ground. It would be clearer to say "Get in the car of someone like that".